# how to use firebase xamarin cross platform?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

How to use firebase in Portable Class Libraries Xamarin.
I want use module Realtime Database, Authentication, Cloud Storage, Cloud Messaging...
I googled but I only see package for native IOS and native Android.
I don't see it for PCL.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check this library package https://components.xamarin.com/view/firebaseioscloudmessaging

Comment: Or Other wise You can actually perform calls to Firebase via REST calls which you can call using standard .Net classes and even with ModernHttpClient library which is a xamarin.plugin

Comment: I checked it. It only use for ios or android.
I want package for PCL use both ios and android.

Comment: I dnt think PCL is available for this, better to use RET calls... hassle free

Comment: A large number of features in those libraries are platform specific, i.e. the Auth UIs, the offline features of Firebase.Database, etc... Assuming you are not going to use any of those, using what is available via the Firebase REST APIs would be the only portable portion.

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover
I found https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin it use Firebase Rest APIs. I trying use it.

Comment: Do you have success in this implementation ?  " PCL use both ios and android"

Comment: Hi All, 
Current I used 
https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet
https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet
https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-storage-dotnet
https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin
I worked good for my project.
Thanks!